# Cannot find a Resource with the Name/Key Locator

Tags: c#, xaml

This worked in my previous projects well,but suddenly there wan an error.

error at static resource Locator(the resource locator cannot be resolved)

```
     <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.DataContext>
    <Binding Path="Main" Source="{StaticResource Locator}"/>
       </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.DataContext>
```

i gave datacontext source in page.xaml.cs  as

```
  private MainViewModel _viewModel { get { return (MainViewModel)DataContext; } }
```

when i navigate to that page.xaml,error thrown as 'xamlparseexception was unhandled' at loadcomponent

Comment: Do you have `Locator` as a resource anywhere(Application, or any other resources)?

Comment: no,only in this location i used locator.And even mvvm light is installed correctly but i couldn't find the solution.

Comment: i fixed myself anyway thanqs for your help,that was an mistake in mvvm light,i removed all my mvvm light dll files and added references again it worked.